# Delete Part Of XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-web-developer

I have a XML file in my Visual Web Developer project that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<complaints>
    <complaint>
        <user>omern</user>
        <content>asd</content>
        <ID>1</ID>
    </complaint>
    <complaint>
        <user>omeromern</user>
        <content>try2</content>
        <ID>2</ID>
    </complaint>
</complaints>
```

I want to delete `complaint` nodes that have and `ID` of 2. How can I do this?

Comment: Mark it with your mouse, then press del key. Make sure to save the file to disk afterwards, otherwise the complaint will still be there the next time you open the file.

P.S.: In case you don't appreciate the humorous aspect of my comment, consider that with the amount of information you gave in your question, this is a perfectly valid solution of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to modify XML documents in C#. Note that this class lives in the `System.Xml.dll` assembly, so you will need to add a reference to `System.Xml` in your project.

```
using System.Xml;
internal class XmlExample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Takes an XML string and removes complaint nodes with an ID of 2.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xml">An XML document in string form.</param>
    /// <returns>The XML document with nodes removed.</returns>
    public static string StripComplaints(string xml)
    {
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.LoadXml(xml);
        XmlNodeList nodes = xdoc.SelectNodes("/complaints/complaint[ID = '2']");
        XmlNode complaintsNode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/complaints");
        foreach (XmlNode n in nodes)
        {
            complaintsNode.RemoveChild(n);
        }

        return xdoc.OuterXml;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                <complaints>
                    <complaint>
                        <user>omern</user>
                        <content>asd</content>
                        <ID>1</ID>
                    </complaint>
                    <complaint>
                        <user>omeromern</user>
                        <content>try2</content>
                        <ID>2</ID>
                    </complaint>
                </complaints>";
xml = XmlExample.StripComplaints(xml);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//using System.Xml;

public string RemoveComplaintWhereIDis(string xml, string id)
{
    XmlDocument x = new XmlDocument();
    xml.LoadXml(xml);
    foreach (XmlNode xn in x.LastChild.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (xn.LastChild.InnerText == id)
        {
            x.LastChild.RemoveChild(xn);
        }
    }
    return x.OuterXml;
}
```

**Basic Usage:**

```
string x = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
             <complaints>
                 <complaint>
                     <user>omern</user>
                     <content>asd</content>
                     <ID>1</ID>
                 </complaint>
                 <complaint>
                     <user>omeromern</user>
                     <content>try2</content>
                     <ID>2</ID>
                 </complaint>
             </complaints>";

string without2 = RemoveComplaintWhereIDis(x, "2");
```